# Bot send message in specific channel

Tags: discord.js

I would like my bot to send a message to a specific channel notifying the user of the completion of the command. However, the channel that the command was executed in is deleted during the command and the message must be sent in a different channel.

I have tried message.channel.sendMessage but I do not know how to set which channel the message sends to.

The command !setup is executed in the default text channels of the guild. During the command, the default channels are deleted and a new channel "reception" is created. I would like the bot to send a message to "reception" to notify the user of the completion of the command.

Answer (score 0):

To find a channel based on its name, you can use [`Collection.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) for the guild's channels ([`Guild.channels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels)).

Example:

```js
const receptionChannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === 'reception');

receptionChannel.send(`Hey ${message.author}, setup is complete.`)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Thanks this works. However, now that I have added this code, the code for deleting the default channels no longer works but there is no error the channels just stay there.

Comment: also do you know how to implement css into the message so that it can send messages in bold or italics for example.

Comment: Gonna need more context to figure out your issue. As for styling, Discord supports [Markdown](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline-).

Comment: So you told me how to delete the default channels before using "defaultChannels.forEach(channel => {
      channel.delete()
            .catch(console.error);"
That code worked fine but now that I have added the "receptionChannel.send('  ')
code to the command the delete channels code no longer deletes the default channels and instead does nothing but doesn't return an error.

Comment: as with the css/markdown part, is there anyway I can use it within a bot message as at the moment using the symbols used in markdown eg: ```,*** etc, start different funtions rather than staying within the string.

Comment: sorry for any inconvenience or annoyance btw

Comment: Not sure what would make the other code not work. To escape characters, put a backslash (\\) before them.